# Emulate the wire part for inductive loop sensor

Tags: inductance

Probably a use case example would show what I am trying to do:

For timing speed of service, inductive loop detection (such as used on traffic light vehicle detection) is used to track cars through a queue. In the past the vendor exposed GPIO pins that the vehicle detect relays would short to ground. To test those systems I could emulate cars going through the queue with toggle switches.

Their newest version now has the vehicle detect built into the tracker so now the detection loop is connected directly to the device's exposed pins. I did try to wrap a cardboard box with wire, connect it to the tracker and it worked. But that is kind of clumsy and would not fit in a reasonable size project box :-). It was nice to just toggle switches to move the car through the queue.

Is there a way to change the inductance by flipping a switch?

Here is what I have for the specs on the loop:

- 18G stranded (oil and gas resistant), 18" x 54" or 18" x 60",6 turns, should read about 3 ohm. I don't have an suitable meter to measure the loop inductance.

Picture of the original (non-builtin) detector. Red and black are power. The clear is the trigger. Green where the loop wires connect. Below that is a picture of the current project box, it is about 5" x 7" Someday I thought of adding LED's. The toggle switch when closed pulls the same pin the clear wire would have connected to to ground.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Paul. I struggled to understand what you were asking mostly due to odd phrasing. I've edited it to clarify so please review. (Hit the 'edited ... minutes ago' link to see the before and after versions.) Edit it yourself if I have misinterpreted. Can you edit to add in the number of turns in a loop or is it only one?

Comment: @Transistor they're normally installed as a single conductor loop.  Fairly plump conductor IIRC.  Paul, i'm having trouble figuring this one out too.  If you can include pictures of the control devices or diagrams of the sensors and line of cars to demonstrate how you want it to behave, we can help you more.

Comment: @Transistor Your editing was spot on, thanks. I did add the number of turns. The spec said 6.

Answer (score 1):

Since the inductance is probably very important to correct operation. A measurement would probably be a good idea.

[image]

*Figure 1. These simple and cheap component testers - search for LCR meter - are very useful. Image source: [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/AVR-Transistor-Tester/).*

Running the All About Circuits[Rectangular loop inductance calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/rectangle-loop-inductance-calculator/) 
I reckon you have about 4 µH inductance per turn. You should be able to get a similar inductance in a small ferrite core package.

> Is there a way to change the inductance by flipping a switch?

Yes. Short-circuit it with the switch.

Alternatively try using two inductors of the required value and have one of them shorted out to simulate the normal situation. Open the switch to increase the inductance to simulate a vehicle arriving on the loop.

Comment: Your ferrite core/Short-circuit suggestion should work and is the kind of trick I was looking for. It maybe a few days before I can test. I will let you know. Looks like all I need is to find the right value. 
BTW this discussion has been helpful beyond getting the lab up. The Instructable and calculator has given me insight into troubleshooting in the field.

Comment: You can purchase the LCR meters readymade on eBay, etc. The EZM328 is one such unit. I have a demo of one I purchased on video at the bottom of https://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/. Here I'm just using it to measure LED voltages.